# Command substitution in docker-compose.yml when scaling a service with multiple instances

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The docker-compose.yml file I am using is following:

```
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "8080-8130:80"
    volumes:
      - ${TEMPDIR}:/run
```

I launch 20 containers with the following command:

```
TEMPDIR=`mktemp -d` docker-compose up -d --scale web=20
```

All of the containers launch ok, but they all have the same temp volume mounted at /run, whereas I need each running container to have a unique temp volume. I understand that the problem is that the above yml file is doing **Variable Substitution** whereas what I need is **Command Substitution** but I could not find any way of doing that in the official [reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/), especially when launching multiple instances of the same docker image. Is there some way to fix this problem?

Comment: The `docker-compose.yml` you try to use performs a bind mount with the source `$TEMPDIR` **on the host** and the target: `/run` **on the container**. The scale will replicate the same container so they will all share the same directory. I do not understand exactly what you are trying to do with the `/run` directory? Could you please tell us what is the objective?

Comment: @Romain I understand what the scale is doing, that's why I said that I need command substitution, not variable substitution. As for the /run, that is just what this particular docker image needs to run properly, I am not really concerned about whether it is /run or any other mount point, I just need the container to run such that $TEMPDIR is unique for each container. If command substitution is not possible, is there any way to do dynamic variable substitution in such **scale** cases?

Comment: I do not think it's possible. However if you want "to run such that $TEMPDIR is unique for each container" you should check my answer below that may answer to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is `tmpfs`.

> Mount a temporary file system inside the container. Can be a single value or a list.

You can use it simply like this

```
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "8080-8130:80"
    tmpfs: /run
```

Here are the references:

- [`tmpfs` on Docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/)
- [`tmpfs` on Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#tmpfs)